# Howto upgrade selected package when composer.lock is present?

Tags: php, composer-php

For an existing library with `composer.json` and `composer.lock` I'd like to upgrade a single dependency to a newer version and make this change minimally invasive.

Problem: if package to be upgraded requires downstream upgrades (A requires B, requires C) that's not possible due to `composer.lock` since the versions of B and C are fixed as well.

As workaround those can be recursively required in newer versions too, but end up in `composer.json` then and need be manually removed.

Is there a more efficient process to manage "minimal change" upgrade of selected requirements?

Note: I don't want to use `composer update` as this will likely change all locked versions if updates exist.

Comment: "As workaround those can be recursively required in newer versions too, but end up in composer.json then and need be manually removed.". Why? If it requires a different version, why not update composer.json?

Comment: Because the dependency on B and C is implicit and shouldn't be managed in composer.json.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. In that case I would probably first `composer remove` the package and then `composer require` the new version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  use

```
composer update your package name
```

or as per documentation you can

```
php composer.phar update vendor/package vendor/package2
```

Ref:
https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update